# Unable to use filename wildcards with s4cmd when trying to copy or sync from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line, aws-cli, s3cmd

I'm trying to use s4cmd to copy files from an AWS S3 bucket using wildcards which are supposedly supported.

For example, I wanted to sync all AWS S3 log files starting with `2017-03-12` to my local current directory:

```
s4cmd sync s3://myapp-logs/prod/2017-03-12-19* .
```

which resulted in *all* files being copied and the wildcard apparently being ignored:

```
s3://myapp-logs/prod/2015-10-08-19-24-42-92BBBE9DA93917D1 => ./prod/2015-10-08-19-24-42-92BBBE9DA93917D1
s3://myapp-logs/prod/2015-10-08-19-30-09-BE8D5466FBB5DFD1 => ./prod/2015-10-08-19-30-09-BE8D5466FBB5DFD1
...
```

I can reproduce this failure regardless of the format of my wildcard.

The only time wildcards work as expected is when I use the `cp` command, e.g.:

```
s4cmd cp s3://myapp-logs/prod/2017-03-12-19* // Note that cp doesn't support copying to a local directory
```

or

```
s4cmd cp s3://mybucket/mystuff/N*.jpg s3://mybuckettest/
```

Comment: Why `s4cmd`? Can't you achieve the same with `aws s3` CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use `aws s3` CLI?

```
aws s3 sync s3://myapp-logs . --exclude "*" --include "*prod/2017-03-12-19*"
```

should work. If it doesn't see [**use-of-exclude-and-include-filters**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) and modify the command.

Comment: The reason I'm using s4cmd (and s3cmd) over the aws s3 cli nowadays is because s4cmd offers some add'l features such as improved syncing (via s4cmd dsync) and I'm trying to use fewer numbers of tools.  *However*, you did remind me that `aws s3` implements wildcard-like functionality via filters, so thank you!  By the way, should `aws s3 sync s3://myapp-logs . --exclude "*" --include "prod/2017-03-12-19*"` be equivalent to `aws s3 sync s3://myapp-logs/prod . --exclude "*" --include "2017-03-12-19*"`?